# SELECT DISTINCTROW Issue MySQL 5 (MariaDB fork)

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my query, let me explain.

**My Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW no,month,year,pin 
FROM db.table 
WHERE date > '2017-11-31'
```

**Database Table**

include the following:

```
| id   | no   | month | year | pin |   date   |
|------|------|-------|------|-----|----------| 
| 24   | 1000 | 12    | 2017 | 521 |2017-12-31|
| 26   | 1000 | 12    | 2020 | 521 |2020-12-31|
| 29   | 1003 | 09    | 2018 | 317 |2018-09-31|
| 30   | 1003 | 09    | 2018 | 317 |2018-09-31|`
```

**so my expected output is the following:**

```
1000, 12, 2017, 521
1000, 12, 2020, 521
1003, 09, 2018, 317
```

> But my query only return the following:

```
null, 12, 2017, 521
1003, 09, 2018, 317
```

**I MEANT BY NULL = EMPTY (nothing displayed)**

**What's Wrong?**

**EDITED**

> my comments removed and corrected the question at all by simple way.

**DATE FORMAT FOR ANY MONTH IS YEAR-MONTH-DAY AND DAYS FOR ANY MONTH IS 31**

> EVEN I TRIED TO RUN THE QUERY WITHOUT query the date but it's do the same

Comment: Please add the corresponding Date values to the question. I don't see a  filed Date.

Comment: is this ms access or sql server ?

Comment: Please indicate data type for `no` and `date` - probably you compare in a wrong way those fields. And why you use `db.table`? Is it linked server table?

Comment: May or may not be contributing to issue: Month, Date, Year are reserved words (intrinsic functions). Enclose in [ ]. Better not to use reserved words as names for anything.

Comment: For `[date]` criteria use `>#11/30/2017#`, current comparison is incorrect, 31 Nov doesn't exist. And remove `no NOT LIKE '0000%'`, for numbers it's not required.

Comment: Remove the "DISTINCTROW"

Comment: That's something strange. `no`cannot be empty, `DISTINCTROW`should not hide the row with different year. Looks like or database is corrupted or you didn't show correct example. Try to copy all objects to new database first.

Comment: `DISTINCTROW` is a quirky option, and it sounds like `DISTINCT` would do fine in your case too. Can you try running the query with `DISTINCT` instead of `DISTINCTROW`?

Comment: *no is include numbers only* that wasn't the question - what **data type** are your columns? If it is a number type, `no NOT LIKE '0000%'` makes no sense.

Comment: [DISTINCT vs DISTINCTROW](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ALL-DISTINCT-DISTINCTROW-TOP-Predicates-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57) -- DISTINCTROW has an effect only when you select fields from some, but not all, of the tables used in the query. DISTINCTROW is ignored if your query includes only one table, or if you output fields from all tables.

Comment: I created a test with the information that your provided and it is working as expected http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92f4ca/2

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT no,month,year,pin ...` instead of `DISTINCTROW`.  You are looking for distinct values of those 4 columns, not the entire row.

(For further discussion, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)